# how can i modify search model for equipments to search by user from other table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I got the users in the equipments view by foreign key, but i can't assign an equipment for a user. I can assign it only to the unique ID from users table.I would also want to be possible to search by user in the equipment view.

If there are any suggestions how to modify this I appreciate very much.

First table : user_id - primary key, username, password ;

Second table: user_equip_id - primary key, phone_model, phone_model_series, phone_date_acq, nb_sg_model, nb_sg,_date_acq, display_model, display_series, display_date_acq, user_for_id - foreign key to user_id from table1

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Equipment;
use app\models\EquipmentSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * EquipmentController implements the CRUD actions for Equipment model.
 */
class EquipmentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Equipment models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new EquipmentSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Equipment model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Equipment model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Equipment();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_equip_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Equipment model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_equip_id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Equipment model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Equipment model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Equipment the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Equipment::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "equipment".
 *
 * @property int $user_equip_id
 * @property string|null $phone_model
 * @property string $phone_series
 * @property string $phone_date_acq
 * @property string $nb_sg_model
 * @property string $nb_sg_series
 * @property string $nb_sg_date_acq
 * @property string $display_model
 * @property string $display_series
 * @property string $display_date_acq
 * @property int $user_for_id
 *
 * @property User $userFor
 */
class Equipment extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'equipment';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['phone_series', 'phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_model', 'display_series', 'display_date_acq', 'user_for_id'], 'required'],
            [['phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_date_acq'], 'safe'],
            [['user_for_id'], 'integer'],
            [['phone_model', 'phone_series', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'display_model', 'display_series'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['user_for_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_for_id' => 'user_id']],
            //[['username'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['username' => 'username']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'user_equip_id' => 'User Equip ID',
            'phone_model' => 'Phone Model',
            'phone_series' => 'Phone Series',
            'phone_date_acq' => 'Phone Date Acq',
            'nb_sg_model' => 'Nb Sg Model',
            'nb_sg_series' => 'Nb Sg Series',
            'nb_sg_date_acq' => 'Nb Sg Date Acq',
            'display_model' => 'Display Model',
            'display_series' => 'Display Series',
            'display_date_acq' => 'Display Date Acq',
            'user_for_id' => 'User For ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[UserFor]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUserFor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_for_id']);
    }
    
    //public function getUsername()
    //{
     //   print_r($equipment->userFor->username);die;
   // }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return EquipmentQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new EquipmentQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

View :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\EquipmentSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Equipments';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="equipment-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Equipment', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            #['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            #'username',
            #'user_equip_id',
            'userFor.username',
            'phone_model',
            'phone_series',
            'phone_date_acq',
            'nb_sg_model',
            'nb_sg_series',
            'nb_sg_date_acq',
            'display_model',
            'display_series',
            'display_date_acq',
            
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

Equipment Search:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Equipment;

/**
 * EquipmentSearch represents the model behind the search form of `app\models\Equipment`.
 */
class EquipmentSearch extends Equipment
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_equip_id', 'user_for_id'], 'integer'],
            [['phone_model', 'phone_series', 'phone_date_acq', 'nb_sg_model', 'nb_sg_series', 'nb_sg_date_acq', 'display_model', 'display_series', 'display_date_acq'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Equipment::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'user_equip_id' => $this->user_equip_id,
            'phone_date_acq' => $this->phone_date_acq,
            'nb_sg_date_acq' => $this->nb_sg_date_acq,
            'display_date_acq' => $this->display_date_acq,
            'user_for_id' => $this->user_for_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone_model', $this->phone_model])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone_series', $this->phone_series])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nb_sg_model', $this->nb_sg_model])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nb_sg_series', $this->nb_sg_series])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'display_model', $this->display_model])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'display_series', $this->display_series]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

**Thank you very much for any suggestions how to get there.**

Comment: First uncomment _search view, there are input that are related to search model. Then replace input for "user_for_id" with some select with options from user tables. Or if you want it in table header:


`[
    'attribute'=>'user_for_id',
    'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->asArray()->all(), 'user_id', 'username'),
],`

Comment: you could take a look at this sample  https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview